# How do i configure php.ini if i don't have access to it

Tags: php

I'm trying to configure my database connection settings in php.ini so that it's at much more safer than putting the password in a php file in the public folder.

Problem is I can't seem to find my php.ini file in my cpanel. I'm using VPS server, not sure if I'm allowed to access this file.

With this limitation, how can I still configure php.ini to contain my host, port, username and password?

Comment: `ini_set()` function is there in php. try to check this through php manual. thanks.

Comment: you cant put your db connection settings in php.ini

Comment: is it a dedicated vps? try this path `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

Comment: if you have a vps, you should have access, find the file with `phpinfo()`

Comment: also, if you are using cPanel, you can make use of cPanel php.ini's advance editor

Answer (score 0):

Adding your db settings to your PHP.ini sounds like strange. I mean, never did it myself.

You can still add configuration settings using a PHP file and not publish that into a public place (folder).

Say if you are in a VPS you can perfectly have your db config outside your public folder -it can be a sibling folder say named "config"- and access that file from your PHP public area if you require it.

Another good idea would be to start thinking about using a PHP Framework like Laravel, Symfony or CakePHP which usually do not place config files under public folders.

Then if you want to access your php.ini file sounds like a good idea using SSH to reach your VPS. You can configure your SSH access in your cPanel.

You have to be versed in Linux console commands then to navigate and edit your php.ini from the command line.

Comment: "Adding your db settings to your PHP.ini sounds like strange." Really? I came across this in several forums and i thought that was the right way to do it. If i follow your method, i should be creating a config folder in the root directory and then access it via my php file from the public folder. Is that right?

Comment: Hi schenker. There is something in the Apache Virtual Hosts called DocumentRoot. This directive tells apache where your public document root will be. But you can install things on your web app outside this Document Root, that are still accessible by your PHP code inside your DocumentRoot. So, yes you can create a config folder and then access it from the public folder.